# Two functions intersect at a complex point

Tags: complex-numbers

English is not my native language

There's something I do not know how to interpret properly .

Suppose I have a straight line $y = 5x$ and a parabola $y = x ^ 2 + 20$. If I look for the point where these functions intersect, we get  $x ^ 2-5x + 20=0$ and  I obtain a complex value . 
The two graphs do not meet anywhere, so, what does this complex number mean? Where are they really meeting if they are?

Thank you

Comment: It means that the equation $f(x)=g(x)$ has no real solutions $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but does have complex solutions $x \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

They meet if you look at them as functions of $\mathbb{C}$, but not as functions of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: With the note that graphs of complex functions are 4-dimensional surfaces, whose intersections are not exactly easy to visualize.

Comment: Exactly. I was trying to make a plot, but it didn't quite work out so far.

Comment: So, if at least we can always have a complex solution, then, it means,  in the complex 4 dimensional surfaces, all functions have common points...that's strange.

Comment: It might seem strange, but it is nothing else than a camouflage of the fundamental theorem of algebra :P. Clearly the "surfaces" must be parametrized by polynomial functions in order for the claimed result to be true.

Comment: An other strange thing is that in case we could visualize four dimensions How can we represent this functions properly where there is no good order for the complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 0):

$y = 5x$ and  $y = x ^ 2 + 20$ are a straight line and a parabola if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, so if the system has not real solution, simply this means that there are no common  points.